# Angular Output send one value through emit

Tags: angular

I have an Output variable that looks like this

```
@Output() selectedValue = new EventEmitter<{in: any, out: any}>();
```

and I'm setting the values on a change event with

```
this.selectedValue.emit({
  in: event.in,
  out: event.out
})
```

My question is. In another part of the app I need to just set the 'in' value and leave the 'out' value alone. Is this possible?

I couldn't find anything on a search and when I tried to omit the out in the emit it yelled at me.

Comment: To do that you'd have to make the `out` optional: `{in: any, out?: any}`

Comment: @jonrsharpe, And how can you do that?

Comment: I included that in the comment too... But other parts of the app shouldn't be emitting through your component's `@Output`.

Answer (score 1):

Please write like this ::

`@Output() selectedValue = new EventEmitter<{ in: any; out?: any }>();`